# How to extract a json file data into a pandas df using Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new on using `JSON` files and came across [this data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MF_BKwy5sass1-tkx0Rmh6XBrcTR3jQi).

I am trying to import it into a pandas dataframe as columns so that I can further work with it. However I think I am running into a nested list for some columns of the data and hence my dataframe looks like this:

[image]

This is a sample of the data I am using:

```
{"fraudulent":false,"customer":
        {"customerEmail":"josephhoward@yahoo.com","customerPhone":"400-108-5415",
        "customerDevice":"yyeiaxpltf82440jnb3v","customerIPAddress":"8.129.104.40",
        "customerBillingAddress":"5493 Jones Islands\nBrownside, CA 51896"},
        "orders":[{"orderId":"vjbdvd","orderAmount":18,"orderState":"pending",
        "orderShippingAddress":"5493 Jones Islands\nBrownside, CA 51896"},
        {"orderId":"yp6x27","orderAmount":26,"orderState":"fulfilled",
        "orderShippingAddress":"5493 Jones Islands\nBrownside, CA 51896"}],
        "paymentMethods":[{"paymentMethodId":"wt07xm68b",
        "paymentMethodRegistrationFailure":true,"paymentMethodType":"card",
        "paymentMethodProvider":"JCB 16 digit",
        "paymentMethodIssuer":"Citizens First Banks"}],"transactions":[
        {"transactionId":"a9lcj51r","orderId":"vjbdvd",
        "paymentMethodId":"wt07xm68b","transactionAmount":18,
        "transactionFailed":false},{"transactionId":"y4wcv03i",
        "orderId":"yp6x27","paymentMethodId":"wt07xm68b",
        "transactionAmount":26,"transactionFailed":false}]}
```

As you can see from the image above, columns like `orders` contain a list of features such as `orderAmount`, `orderState` etc. I want those values to be split into their only column so I get a pandas data frame with all features as separate columns with their corresponding values.

So far I have tried using `json_normalize` but that did not resolve my issue.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, given what you've said, the first thing you should do is unravel that JSON like so to make it easier to understand:

```
{
    "fraudulent":false,
    "customer": {
            "customerEmail":"josephhoward@yahoo.com",
            "customerPhone":"400-108-5415",
            "customerDevice":"yyeiaxpltf82440jnb3v",
            "customerIPAddress":"8.129.104.40",
            "customerBillingAddress":"5493 Jones Islands\nBrownside, CA 51896"
        },
    "orders":[
        {
            "orderId":"vjbdvd",
            "orderAmount":18,
            "orderState":"pending",
            "orderShippingAddress":"5493 Jones Islands\nBrownside, CA 51896"
        },
        {
            "orderId":"yp6x27",
            "orderAmount":26,
            "orderState":"fulfilled",
            "orderShippingAddress":"5493 Jones Islands\nBrownside, CA 51896"}
        ],
    "paymentMethods":[
            {
                "paymentMethodId":"wt07xm68b",
                "paymentMethodRegistrationFailure":true,"paymentMethodType":"card",
                "paymentMethodProvider":"JCB 16 digit",
                "paymentMethodIssuer":"Citizens First Banks"
            }
        ],
    "transactions":[
            {
                "transactionId":"a9lcj51r","orderId":"vjbdvd",
                "paymentMethodId":"wt07xm68b","transactionAmount":18,
                "transactionFailed":false
            },
            {
                "transactionId":"y4wcv03i",
                "orderId":"yp6x27","paymentMethodId":"wt07xm68b",
                "transactionAmount":26,"transactionFailed":false
            }
        ]
}
```

The next thing to think about is how to structure the DataFrame. By the looks of your data, you will probably have to split this over multiple dataframes since it appears that transactions, payments, and orders might have variable length.

So you could have one DataFrame where each row corresponds to a customer, with a corresponding ID for each customer (or just use something unique like their email), and then have a column for all orders, with a column containing that ID that relates it back to customer DataFrame.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

customers = []
orders = []
paymentMethods = []
transactions = []

with open('data.json') as f:
    raw_json = json.load(f)

customer_id = 0
for i in raw_json:
    customers.append([
        customer_id,
        i['fraudulent'],
        i['customer']['customerEmail'],
        i['customer']['customerPhone'],
        i['customer']['customerDevice'],
        i['customer']['customerIPAddress'],
        i['customer']['customerBillingAddress'],
    ])

    for j in i['orders']:
        orders.append([
            customer_id,
            j['orderId'],
            j['orderAmount']
            # etc
        ])
    # etc
    customer_id += 1



customers_df = pd.DataFrame(data=customers, columns=['customer_id', 'fraudulent', 'customerEmail', 'customerPhone', 'customerDevice', 'customerIPAddress', 'customerBillingAddress'])

orders_df = pd.DataFrame(data=orders, columns=['customer_id', 'orderId', 'orderAmount'])
```

You will need to expand that answer to fully parse the JSON, but that should give a good start. See the way `customer_id` is used to relate the entries in `customers_df` with `orders_df`.

I'd look at the Pandas docs for more information about constructing a Dataframe [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: Hello, this does not work for me. I am getting an error saying "JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 1047)". You can take a look at how the data is structured by following the link to the data in the question.

Comment: Is that data you provided an example of one row?

Comment: How does that look?